# problem in responsive nav-bar for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-development-server

I have written this script for nav-bar, which should act as a toggle button. on first click, it should open menu and on second click it should close.

I couldn't understand the problem.

**Script:**

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const togg = document.querySelector('.toggle');
  const navs = document.querySelector('nav-links');

  togg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navs.classList.toggle('nav_ul_active');
  });
}
```

**Related Html Code**:

```html
<div class="toggle" onclick="navSlide()">
  <div class="menu"> <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul class="nav_ul">
    <li><a href="#head-proj">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#head-about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now when I refresh my website and click on button, this error gets displayed:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
>       at HTMLDivElement. (app.js:6)

here app.js is my javascript file. What is this error and how should I clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) expects a CSS selector string. Use a dot to signify a class name:

```
document.querySelector('.nav-links')
```

See [Class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors#Class_selectors).

Also, you're binding a click handler that binds another click handler.  The result is that a new handler is bound to the element each time you click it. I recommend removing the inline `onclick` attribute and relying on `addEventListener`.

```js
const togg = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const navs = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

togg.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navs.classList.toggle('nav_ul_active');
});
```

```css
.nav_ul_active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="toggle">
  <div class="menu"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul class="nav_ul">
    <li><a href="#head-proj">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#head-about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed my onclick attribute and its working fine. Thanks for the suggestion.